# MongoDB scheme on a big project

Tags: mongodb, performance, code-cleanup, nosql

We recently started to work in a big project and we decided to use MongoDB as a DDBB solution.

We wrote a lot of code, but the project has started to grow and we found out that we're trying to use `join`s instead of doing it the `NoSQL`way, which denotes a bad DDBB design.

What I'm trying to ask here is a good design for our project, which, at this point consists of the following:

- More than 12.000 Products
- More than 2.000 Sellers

Every seller should have its own private area that will allow to create a product catalog based on the +12.000 "products template list".

The seller should be able to set the price, stock and offers, which will then be reflected only in his public product listing. The template list of products will remain unchanged.

Currently we have two collections. One for the products (which holds the general product information, like name, description, photos, etc...) and one collection in which we store documents that contain the ID of the product from the first collection, an ID that is related to the seller and the stock, price and offers values.

We are using `aggregate` with `$lookup` to "emulate" SQL's left join to merge the two collections, but the process is not scaling as we'd like it to and we're hitting serious performance issues.

We're aware that using joins is not the way to go in NoSQL. What should we do? How should we refactor our DDBB design? Should we embed the prices, offers and stock for each seller in each document?

Comment: Why are you using mongo?

Comment: We had a meeting before start the project an decided that MongoDB could give us more benefits than demage. 12K products and 2K sellers is just a demo data, it could be millions and millions in a future.

Comment: A relational database is capable of managing efficiently billions of rows, not only millions...

Comment: @Renzo Well, you might even successfully use Redis for the application – or flat files. That does not make it a good choice. And given the scalability and failover capabilities of most RDBMS, we could argue for a _very_ long time wether any relational database actually is a good choice here.

Comment: @Nache Please provide sample documents.

Answer (score 1):

The decision of using "Embedded documents" or "Joins among two or more different collections" should depend on how you are going to retrieve the data.If every time,while fetching product, you are going to fetch sellers,then it makes sense to make it an embedded document instead of different collections.But if you will be planning to fetch these two entities separately, then only option you are left with is to use Join.